# How do I cast from char** to char* in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, char, strcmp

I have this problem:
I have a matrix in which stores diferent characters. Now I have to compare these characters to another one, but when compiling, it says strcmp recives char* and I have char**. So, how do I cast it?
This is the code I have:

For the matrix:

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++){
            if (!fscanf(fol, "%c", &mat[i][j])){
                break;}
            //printf("%c", mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

The part I have problems with:

```
    for (x = 0; x < largo; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < ancho; y++){
            char *charcha;
            strcpy (charcha, mat[x][y]);

            //char *charcha = "%c", mat[x][y];
            int algo = strcmp(charcha, "0");
            if (algo == 0){
                printf (" ");
                }
            else{
            printf("%c", mat[x][y]);}
            }
            }

    printf ("\n");
```

I tried with strcpy, but it failed as well :C

Thanks

Comment: as-is charcha is an uninitialized pointer that's passed to strcpy.

Comment: `if (algo == 0){` --> `if (mat[x][y] == '0'){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare strings, use:

```
for (x = 0; x < largo; x++)
{
   if ( strcmp(mat[x], "0") == 0 )
   {
      // Do whatever.
   }
   else
   {
      // Do whatever.
   }
}
```

If you want to compare characters, use:

```
for (x = 0; x < largo; x++)
{
   for (y = 0; y < ancho; y++)
   {
      if (mat[x][y] == '0' )
      {
         // Do whatever.
      }
      else
      {
         // Do whatever.
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To go from char** to char* use *

example:

```
char ** twoLevel = ..
char * oneLevel = *twoLevel;
```